# Update function not working in vb.net

Tags: oracle

Currently I'm develop a system using VB.NET. I have the following query for UPDATE. This query is work when I run in SQL Developer

```
UPDATE CCS2_TBL_INSPECTION_STANDARD SET CCSEQREVITEM = :CCSEQREVITEM, 
CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = TO_DATE(:CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE 
CCSEQID = :CCSEQID
```

But when I try applied this query in VB.net, its not work. Actually the flow for this update function is work but when I update the data, it is not working. For example, I want update name from 'Ali' to 'Abu', when I click the update button, there popup windows says that "Update success" but the name is not change to 'Abu', it still 'Ali'. There no error when I execute. Anyone know? Below VB.net code:

```
Protected Sub editInspectionRev(eqid As String)

Dim xSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder
xSQL.AppendLine("UPDATE CCS2_TBL_INSPECTION_STANDARD")
xSQL.AppendLine("SET")
xSQL.AppendLine("CCSEQREVITEM = :CCSEQREVITEM, CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = TO_DATE(:CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')")
xSQL.AppendLine("WHERE CCSEQID = :CCSEQID")

Using cn As New OracleConnection(ConString)
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(xSQL.ToString, cn)
    cmd.Connection = cn


    cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQREVITEM", txtRevContent.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE", txtRevEffDate.Text)


    cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQID", eqid)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()

End Using
success3.Visible = True
DisplayRevisionDetails()

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to commit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have executed the transaction but failed to `COMMIT` it. There is an example of the correct method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), which I will reproduce in part below for posterity

```
Using connection As New OracleConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim command As OracleCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
    Dim transaction As OracleTransaction

    ' Start a local transaction
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    ' Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
    command.Transaction = transaction

    ...

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    transaction.Commit()
```

Observe that we have begun the transaction, and then committed it after executing.

Comment: Just to complement, Oracle works always in a transactional state. It's always waiting for a Commit or Rollback. The reason why the OP saw the values in Sql developer, it's because he was making the query in the same session. In another session, he wouldn't also see the values. Although @Gaius suggestion is valid, it would work if you just added the commit statement after the update on the sql command.

Comment: Well, not _always_, you can if you wish `SET AUTOCOMMIT ON` ;-)

Comment: True :) . My bad.